# Flex: Blank page when using builder compiled swf

Tags: apache-flex, ant, weblogic, flash

I got a blank swf when compiling with builder. Everything works fine when compile with ant and deploy my ear file to weblogic. Im using Flash Builder 4.0 and sdk 4.5.

Comment: If i restart weblogic managed server, builder compiled swf will work.

Answer (score 1):

Blank SWF? did you mean empty SWF (low size) or are you refering to the display in a web browser?

It might be a security issue in the browser, might want to make sure the flash security console has a permission for your files location.

Comment: My web container was so messed up. When i cleared it, it started to work.